# If a language and its complement are context-free, is it regular?

Tags: automata, regular-language, context-free-grammar

If both $L$ and $\overline{L}$ are context-free, is $L$ necessarily regular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every deterministic context-free language satisfies this, since the deterministic context-free languages are closed under complementation. Not all deterministic context-free languages are regular, for example $\{ a^n b^n : n \geq 0 \}$ isn't.